# save trees corrupted references

Tags: savetrees

I am using save trees package to reduce the number of pages in latex. However, the references is getting corrupted. That is., it is introducing some unnecessary line breaks in-between authors. Hence, I didn't want save trees to modify my references. I check the documentation of save trees (http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/savetrees/savetrees.pdf) and introduced the following code.

```
\usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}  
 .......  
 .......
 \makeatletter  
 \@st@tight@bibliographyfalse  
 \makeatother
 \begin{document}  
 .............  
 .............  
 .............  
 \end{document}
```

The above code didn't work and I am still having unnecessary line breaks between authors in references. How to disable save trees not modify anything on bibliography?

Answer (score 3):

The problem relates to the paragraph option ("Discourage TEX from allowing the last line of a paragraph to contain only a single word.").
So setting the looseness back to 0 before the bibliography did it for me:

```
    \markeverypar{\the\everypar\looseness=0 } 
    \bibliographystyle{savetrees}
    \bibliography{literature}
```